# MoveTask in phing to slow

Tags: move, phing

Currently building a build process with phing. Each time I want to deploy to live, I move the staging version with the following command

```
<move file="${next_version}" tofile="${current_version}" />
```

but, since move kind of inherits from copy (as stated in the documentation), this procedure really takes some time and is not comparible to any shell move command. Is there a metter way to call move, or do I have to fallback to the execTask (seeing no sense in move then, at least in that case)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The move task really copies files, which is crap. Please open a feature request on the phing bug tracker.